# Ember HTML attribute with spaces

Tags: ember.js

I have this Bootstrap accordion item

```
{{#bs-accordion-item value=index title=client.name}}
```

But I would like the `title` attribute to contain a string with a mix of variable data and static text, such as `title="{{client.value}} at {{client.name}}"` but since I can't use the quotes I'm stuck...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `concat` helper.

```
{{#each model as |rental|}}
  {{#bs-accordion selected=selected}}
    {{#bs-accordion-item value=rental.id title=(concat rental.title " Owned by " rental.owner)}}
        {{!--The accordion content goes here--}}
    {{/bs-accordion-item}}
  {{/bs-accordion}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what [Computed Properties in Ember](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/object-model/computed-properties/) are for...

You can construct the desired string using a computed property in your controller, for example, and assign the computed property to the `title` attribute.

In the controller, you could do something like this:

```
client: {
  name: 'Indianapolis Motor Speedway',
  value: 'Alexander Rossi',
},

constructedString: Ember.computed('client.value', 'client.name', function () {
  const clientValue = this.get('client.value');
  const clientName = this.get('client.name');

  return `${clientValue} at ${clientName}`; 
}),
```

In the bs-accordion-item helper, the `constructedString` value is assigned to the `title` attribute:

```
{{ bs-accordion-item value=index title=constructedString }}
```

And the bs-accordion-item template could then reference `title`, like so:

```
<h3>{{ title }}</h3>
```

I've created an [Ember Twiddle example](https://ember-twiddle.com/7d382dae14b0e2934b74d9aea3bc9626) to demonstrate.

Comment: It would be best if you could add a code example to your code to protect against dead links.

Comment: In this simple case, is there any advantage to using a computed property over `concat` as suggested by @Falke?

Comment: @user2239595 His is easier. But this answer is more conventional. It has less magic in your template. Data handling concerns would/should be isolated in the controller, or even better, your [component and a service](https://emberigniter.com/5-essential-ember-concepts/) (see components backed by services, and controllers going away). This is a perfect use case for computed properties, an Ember convention, as opposed to relying on a template helper for some things, and data from computed properties for other data.